# Find $W_1$ branch of Lambert $W$-function

Tags: lambert-w

The given equation:
$$\frac{8} {\ln(2)} \cdot \ln(x) = x.$$

Some algebra, and then we get the solutions:

$$x = e^{W_0(-\frac{\ln(2)} {8})}\approx 1.1
,\;\;
x = e^{W_{-1}(-\frac{\ln(2)} {8})} \approx  43.5593.$$

I found $W_{0}$ with Taylor series.

But there is addition real solution, $W_{-1}$.

How I find the $W_{-1}$?

Comment: You could just edit your original question instead of posting a new one. You may use http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E6 for the other branch with $$
t =  - \sqrt {2\left( { - 1 - \log \left( {\frac{{\log 2}}{8}} \right)} \right)} .
$$

Comment: Btw, how is $W_0 = e^W$?

Comment: Sorry, i meant $x = e^{W}$
The $W_{0}$ is to say that for this x i apply $W_{0}$ and not the $W_{-1}$

Comment: Thanks @Gary . but I'm not fully understand how did I find the $C_{n}$ ? and how did you get to this this t?. is there any simpler series representation for $W_{-1}$ with n's and constants, like we found the $W_{0}$ ?

Comment: If you look below the formula I linked, there is a recurrence for the coefficients. There is no simple series for $W_{-1}(z)$ like the one for $W_0(z)$ because it is not analytic at $z=0$. With my $t$, $$
 - e^{ - 1 - t^2 /2}  =  - \frac{{\log 2}}{8}
$$ and that is what you wanted.